# Preflight response won't accept my header params

Tags: angular, rest, codeigniter, cors

I have written a REST API using CodeIgniter 3.0. I am trying to make calls to this API using Angular 2.0 Http module inside of a service.

Anytime I include a header parameter in the request, this error is thrown.

`Request header field apikey is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Here is the code that calls upon the REST API

```
 login(email, pass): Observable<any> {
    //url 
    let url = `${this.ApiAuthBase}/login`;

    //header params
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('apikey', 'fruits');

    //body params 
    let userParams = new FormData();
    userParams.append('email', email);
    userParams.append('password', pass);

    //fire api request
    return this.http.post(url, userParams, {headers: headers}).map(res=>res.json())
  }
```

The REST API configuration allows CORS and `apikey` is in Allowed-Headers property. Its necessary for me to pass a header param from Angular 2. This issue does not occur when interfacing the API from iOS or Node.JS. Has anyone ran into this issue? All help is greatly appreciated.

```
$config['check_cors']  = TRUE;

$config['allowed_cors_headers'] = [
  'Origin',
  'X-Requested-With',
  'Content-Type',
  'Accept',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method',
  'token',
  'apikey'
];
$config['allowed_cors_methods'] = [
  'GET',
  'POST',
  'OPTIONS',
  'PUT',
  'PATCH',
  'DELETE'
];
$config['allow_any_cors_domain'] = FALSE;
$config['allowed_cors_origins'] = ['*'];
```

Cheers !

Comment: maybe you can share the actual HTTP headers that are being returned. There's likely something wrong there, and that might give you a hit. As a sidenote: `apikey` is of course non-standard, and you might want to use the standard `Authorization` header for this.

Comment: Have you tried setting `$config['allow_any_cors_domain'] = TRUE`? Because by doing `$config['allowed_cors_origins'] = ['*']` it seems like your intent is to allow cross-origin requests from any origin. I’m not familiar with whatever backend that config is for, but maybe `$config['allowed_cors_origins'] = ['*']` doesn’t have the effect you intend. Maybe the value of that option is only intended to contain an explicit list of origins, and not the `*` wildcard. Otherwise there wouldn’t be any need for a separate `allow_any_cors_domain` option…

Comment: My server configuration matches the suggestions that both of you kindly gave. The Angular2 app can make calls to the API when no header params are involved. As soon as a value is passed in the header, the server returns 405 Method Not Found.